# flash as3 - aligning bottom edge of movieclips programmatically

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

I want to accomplish the same thing with code that Flash's Align - Align Bottom Edge button does within the IDE. I have a series of move clips of different heights which are all added to the stage dynamically via XML. When they are all added, I want to then align them - does flash provide a method for doing this with code? Or is the only way to do it to detect their heights and adjust them by the height difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That functionality is not present in the base ActionScript classes. You only have height, width, x, y, z properties in DisplayObject, Shape, MovieClip, etc.

The Flex framework offers advanced layout functions (horizontal and vertical align in the BasicLayout, as well as top/bottom/right/left positioning constraints). There might be other lightweight frameworks that offer this functionality ("coordy" by someRandomDude comes to mind: http://somerandomdude.com/work/coordy/)

Comment: Thanks for the link - that's pretty sweet.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything like that build in, but it would be pretty easy to do manually using MovieClip's `height` property.

```
// assume you have all your movie clips in an array called myClips
for each(var mc:MovieClip in myClips){
    // align all the bottom edges at 100 pixels
    mc.y = 100 - mc.height; 
}
```